# How to proof $\forall n>0: 5|(6^n-1)$ is true using mathematical induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, proof-explanation

This is what i did so far, i got stuck on the later steps of using mathematical induction

I started with a base of $1$ which gave me $5|5$ which is $1$. Then I used $n = k$, and i got $5|(6^k-1)$ and i assumed this was true, but when i got to $n = k+1$ i didnt knew how to implement $5|(6^k-1)$ to $5|(6^{k+1}-1)$ to show that the theorem is true. For the real assignment, check this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhF9S.jpg

Comment: To start with, what happened when you applied the definition of the divisibility operator $|$ to the statement $5 | (6^n-1)$?

Comment: Look at my comment on one of these answers

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$5|(6^k-1)$$
implies
$$6^k=5p+1$$

for some integer $p$.

Or, write
$$6^{k+1}-1=6\times 6^k -1$$
$$=6*(6^k-1)+6-1$$

Comment: I can see why you did that. Since 5|((6^k)−1), there must exist an integer p such that (6^k)-1 = 5p, but what after that

Comment: Hint: After above step, we have $6^k.6=6(5p+1)=5p'+6$

Comment: @Amasya05 What about the second hint?

Comment: Do you mean the one in your answer, or the one of AnotherJohnDoe

Comment: @Amasya05 The second hint in my answer.

Comment: Hmm, it just seems like you moved a few part of the equation around.

Comment: @Amasya05 If $5$ divides something, will $5$ divide 6 times something +5?

Comment: Yes, why not, 5 is equal to 5 and if 5 divides something it surely can divide the same number multiplied a few times

Comment: @Amasya05 So put that "something" to be $6^k-1$.

Comment: So if 5 divides (6^k)−1, 5 also devides 6((6^k)-1)+5. But how does this lead to a proof

Comment: Yes my bad, changed it

Comment: So can you simplify $6(6^k -1)+5$?

Comment: So  ((6^k+1) -6) +5 if i am right

Comment: @Amasya05 You can simplify the $-6+5$ further

Comment: Oh true, we get ((6^k+1)-1)

Answer (score 0):

let $$T_n=6^n-1$$ and $$5|6^n-1$$ now let $$T_{n+1}=6^{n+1}-1$$ and we get
$$T_{n+1}-T_n=5\cdot 6 ^n$$ therefore $$5|T_{n+1}$$

Comment: hmm okay, so Tn is then for example 5p or 5l, depending on the letter you choose, same holds for Tn+1. But why would you substract them from eachother

Comment: since $$T_{n+1}=5\cdot 6^n+T_n$$ both numbers on the right-hand side are divisible by $5$ thus $$T_{n+1}$$ is also divisible by $5$

Comment: @Amasya05 Something to add here that might make it clearer - $$\begin{align}T_{n+1}&=6^{n+1}-1\\&=6\cdot 6^n-1\\&=5\cdot 6^n+1\cdot6^n-1\\&=5\cdot6^n+T_n\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You have assumed that $$5|(6^k-1)$$ This means that $6^k-1=5m$ for some (natural) number $m$.

Firstly, to turn the $6^k$ into a $6^{k+1}$, multiply the whole equation by $6$ to give $$6^{k+1}-6=30m$$Then to get the $-1$, just subtract $1$ from both sides and rearrange a bit to give $$6^{k+1}-6-1=30m-1\\6^{k+1}-1=30m-1+6\\6^{k+1}-1=30m+5\\6^{k+1}-1=5(6m+1)$$

Comment: Hmmm, wait why did you multiply te whole equation by 6?

Comment: When doing induction, you want to go from the assumed thing you have with $k$ to the next step, $k+1$. So to increase the power in $6^k$ to $6^{k+1}$, you must multiply by $6$.

Comment: Okay, but why does the +1 stay then if we multiplied everythign by 6

Comment: @Amasya05 It doesn't. I edited my answer to make the steps clearer.

Comment: I think you got me wrong and me not understanding everything and it being late makes everything worse. with +1 i meant the +1 in (6^k+1). I think this +1 needs to be removed at the end because we already multiplied the whole eqaution by 6 right? And i font get why you subrrat 1 from both sides now.

Comment: Why would that +1 be removed? When you multiply by 6, the power increases. After that we don't divide by 6, so why would the power go back to just $6^k$?

Answer (score 0):

**With induction.** If $5|6^n-1$, then there is $q_n$ such that $6^n-1=5\cdot q_n$. Note that
$$
6^{n+1}-1=6\cdot 6^n-1=5\cdot 6^n+6^n-1=5(6^n+q_n)
$$
**Without induction.**
\begin{align}
6^n-1 
=&
(5+1)^n-1
\\
=&
(5^{n}+n\cdot 5^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot 5^{n-2}+\cdots+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot 5^2+ n\cdot5+1)-1
\\
=&
5^{n}+n\cdot 5^{n-1}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot 5^{n-2}+\cdots+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot 5^2+ n\cdot5
\\
=&
5\cdot (5^{n-1}+n\cdot 5^{n-2}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot 5^{n-3}+\cdots+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot 5+ n)
\\
\end{align}

Comment: Woooww, whats the thing with the first part, first equation untill all of those long equations

Comment: @Amasya05 Binomial expansion

Comment: $(5+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}5^{k}1^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}5^{k}1^{n-k}$

Comment: Oh well, i didnt get that at school yet. So its a bit too complicated for me, atleast for now. I just had 1 binomial coefficent that i needed to proof something with and thats it

Answer (score 0):

Step: $5|(6^{n+1} -1)$

$6^{n+1} -1 = 6^n6 -1=$

$6^n (1+5) -1 = 6^n-1 +5(6^n).$

$5|(6^n -1)$  $\rightarrow$  $(6^n -1)= 5s$.

$6^{n+1} - 1 = 5s + 5(6^n) = 5(s+6^n).$

Hence:

$5|(6^{n+1} -1).$